# SPOT and LANDSAT images on the same grid

Tags: tiles, landsat

Let us introduce ourselves, we are a GIS team of the Cartographic division of INDEC (the national census bureau of Argentina). We are working on the next national Agricultural Census 2018, which will be carried out on Tablets with Android O.S., running Leaflet to show the maps.

We have strong storage restrictions (SD 16 GB memory) and the whole program (images included) has to run local on the tablet (no internet signal in the most areas to be covered).

We get a province-wide 30mts, LANDSAT mosaic, resampled at 15mts with the monochromatic band (each pair: census taker/tablet) are restricted to only one province.

But for some zones (intensive agricultural use) we need SPOT 2,5 mts images.

We get to generate the tiled pyramid of the 15mts landsat, using GDAL gdal2tile

```
gdal2tiles.py -t "BS AS" -c INDEC -z 0-8 -e -d -a 0 -p raster -v -s EPSG:22185 -r cubic /BsAsGK5.tif /tiles_bs_as
```

After that we convert the png files to jpg, using:

```
find tiles_bsas -iname '.png' | while read i; do mogrify -format jpg "$i" && rm "$i"; echo "Converted $i to ${i%.}.jpg"; done
```

Here is our question: How should we generate the tiled pyramids of the 2,5 mts SPOT images in a way that both images use the same grid without 'resampling' the whole landsat to 2,5mts, of course. :)

If you are willing to give us some advice, we will send you the links to some sample images.

Link to LANDSAT 15mts. example (prov of BsAs) 6.5GB

Link to SPOT 2,5mts. example (Department of San Pedro) 2.3GB